# AWS CloudWatch logs: How to send an email notification when particular error message is logged by lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cloudwatch-alarms

I have to monitor CloudWatch logs for particular lambda. When the specific error message such as HTTP-50X is logged to CloudWatch, then we need to send an email notification to alert that the something is wrong.

We need help to create alert email in AWS to monitor manually the logs to see if there is any such error logged.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution precisely aims to use cloudwatch or any solution that may solve sending an email when error occurs in a particular lambda ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Ersoy, Yes, need help to create alert email in AWS.

Answer (score 13):

This is exactly what [metric filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringPolicyExamples.html) is for. Create a metric filter that monitors your log group for specific pattern. Then create a CloudWatch alarm based on a new metric and configure it with an SNS action. Then simply subscribe your email to that SNS topic.

All of this can be easily done via CloudFormation([Metric filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-metricfilter.html), [Alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html), [SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html)). You can also use [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html).

Comment: How could I include the log message in these email notifications. I only receibe. info about the alarm itself.  Thanks.

Comment: @Aleix As far as I am concerned, you cannot do this. I am also looking for a solution on how to do this.

Comment: @TomasLukac were you able to find something to approach this?

Comment: @Aleix that is exactly what I am looking for. Found anything?

Answer (score 6):

You can process/monitor logs in real-time using lambda functions. Checkout [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchlogs.html) and [Real-time Processing of Log Data with Subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) for details.